# How do I make a table of tuples with their respective averages in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have defined a function in Mathematica as getavglist[w_?ListQ]:=N[Map[Mean,Tuples[w,2]]]. I want to add to this function by making it a table with it's tuples. For example if I had a list equal to {2,3,4,5} I would like for the function to make a table like {{{2,2},2},{{2,3},2.5},{{2,4},3},{{2,5},3.5},etc.}. I have tried several different methods but none seem to work. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `getavglist[w_?ListQ]:=Map[{#,N[Mean[#]]}&,Tuples[w,2]]` or you could try `tupleAndMean[t_]:={t,N[Mean[t]]}; getavglist[w_?ListQ]:=Map[tupleAndMean,Tuples[w,2]]` which means less having to learn what `#` and `&` means.

Comment: @Bill What resources can I use to learn more about using Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: There are an assortment of books, some on paper, some digital. Some of those are old, but for the basics of the language that shouldn't matter much. Some of those are available in libraries. Some cheap and used on Amazon or allbookstores.com can look for a cheaper copy. There are some classes. Google "wolfram language" site:wolfram.com and see what that turns up for you. If you have previous experience in another programming language then some of that will help and some of that will make it harder. The Wolfram Language is very different from many other programming languages. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a function that gives you the entire table. I'll take advantage of the opportunity to introduce you to `With` and `Compose` (`@*`).

```
makeTable[ws_] := With[{tuples2 = Tuples[ws, 2]},
  Transpose[{tuples2, N@*Mean /@ tuples2}]]
```

Example use:

```
ws = {2, 3, 4, 5}
makeTable[ws]
TableForm[%, TableDepth -> 2]
```